# Don't know how to access a second page with Vue Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to add Vue Router to one of my projects to be able to navigate between some pages.

I am not familiar with Vue Router so I might have done something wrong.

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'
import App from '../App'
import Test from '../Views/Test'


const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path:'',
            name: 'App',
            component: App,
        },
        {
            path:'/test',
            name: 'Test',
            component: Test
        }
    ]
})
export default router
```

Here is my `index.js` file. My problem is that when I run my code, I can see my App page without problems but when I manually go to http://localhost:8080/test I have an error saying that the page has not been found

Could you help me with that?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

I have changed a few things and I am now able to access my pages, but only with a router-link.
I have added a `First.vue` page in which i can choose to go to my `App.vue` or to my `Test.vue`.

My `First.vue`:

```
<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
    
    <router-link to='/app'>Go to application</router-link>
    <br>
    <router-link to='/test'>Go to test</router-link>
    
</template>
```

and my ìndex.js` is now looking like this:

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'
import App from '../App.vue'
import Test from '../Views/Test.vue'
import First from '../Views/First.vue'


const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path:'/',
            name: 'First',
            component: First,
        },
        {
            path:'/test',
            name: 'Test',
            component: Test
        },
        {
            path:'/app',
            name: 'App',
            component: App
        }
    ]
})
export default router
```

Comment: Use `http://localhost:8080/#/test` instead

Comment: @bel3atar When I do that, it just shows my app, not my test page

Comment: are you sure you are actually using the router? Do you call ```app.use(router)```?

Comment: @ThomasKuhlmann Yes, this is my main.js : 
`import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app') `

Comment: Clarify "I have an error saying that the page has not been found". Where do you see that? Is that a `404`?

Comment: Also, the `path` for `App` should be `/`, not `''`.

Comment: @tony19 The page shows 'cannot GET /test' and in the console, I have `GET http://localhost:8080/test 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: You can use this template https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-4-reproduction-s1sqc

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-surf-f2xnr?file=/src/router/index.js
Here it is, but I have some problems to access my index.js that I don't have in my project, event if the files and folders are tthe same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing your sandbox, I think the problem is your export and import statement, they don't match.

If you export your module like this:

```
export const router = createRouter({
  ...
});
```

the import statement should be

```
import { router } from "./router/index";
```

If you export your module like this:

```
const router = createRouter({
  ...
});
export default router;
```

the import statement should be

```
import router from "./router/index";
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me, I still have the error when trying to access http://localhost:8080/test :((

Comment: It seems the original question is centred around vue-router 4 - ```history: createWebHistory()``` is how you set the history mode with the new version, so that's already been done

Comment: After analyzing your sandbox, I have figure out the problem. It's not about your vue-router setting up, but about how you export and import your router. I have updated the comment.

Comment: @ThomasKuhlmann Yup, I didn't notice that =))))